# Почему данные вставляются не туда, куда нужно?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, mariadb

Есть таблица books:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно добавить номера isbn из другой таблицы (всего номеров isbn 2 шт.) в таблицу books в строки, где есть значения в столбцах title и price

Другая таблица под названием t1:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
SQL-запрос:

```
INSERT INTO books(isbn) SELECT DISTINCT isbn FROM t1 WHERE title <> "";
```

Что получается при выполнении запроса:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Почему происходит именно так? И как мне сделать так, чтобы номера isbn вставлялись туда, где в столбцах title и price есть значения.**

Comment: INSERT всегда вставляет новые записи. Для корректировки существующих используйте UPDATE. Однако я не вижу данных,  позволяющих установить, какой isbn какой записи принадлежит.

Comment: @Akina понял, сейчас попробую изменить SQL-запрос

Comment: @Akina я дополнил вопрос таблицей t1 для наглядности

Comment: Ну тады связывать либо по (title, price), либо чисто по title. Либо мержить по title, заодно обновляя price. Тут уже всё зависит от бизнес-логики.

Comment: Я не понимаю как составить запрос с UPDATE. Пробую вот так: 
UPDATE books SET books.isbn = t1.isbn WHERE books.title = t1.title;

Генерируется сообщение об ошибке: #1054 - Неизвестный столбец 't1.title' в 'where clause'


p.s. работаю в PMA

Comment: У тебя multi-table UPDATE, а в источнике данных сфига-то только одна таблица. См. мануал, что ли...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильный SQL-запрос:

```
UPDATE books, t1 SET books.isbn = t1.isbn WHERE books.title = t1.title;
```